# Getting Duplicate Labeled Points on Scatterplot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use kmeans to show what states have similar statistics with one another from the Lahman database, my code is as follows:

```
battingInfo <- Batting %>% filter(yearID >= 1999)
total <- merge(battingInfo,People,by="playerID")
totalN <- total[,-c(24,25,28:47)]
filterByState <- totalN %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise(players = length(playerID)) 
newMerge <- merge(totalN, filterByState, by="birthState")
newTest <- newMerge %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise_at(vars(G, AB, R, H, X2B, X3B, HR, RBI, SB, CS, BB,
                                                                   SO, IBB, HBP, SH, SF, GIDP), sum, na.rm =  TRUE)
updateTest <- newMerge %>% group_by(birthState) %>% summarise(Players = n_distinct(playerID), G = sum(G), AB = sum(AB),
                                                              R = sum(R), H = sum(H), X2B = sum(X2B), X3B = sum(X3B),
                                                              HR = sum(HR), RBI = sum(RBI), SB = sum(SB), CS = sum(CS),
                                                              BB = sum(BB), SO = sum(SO), IBB = sum(IBB), HBP = sum(HBP),
                                                              SH = sum(SH), SF = sum(SF), GIDP = sum(GIDP))

finalUpdate <- newMerge %>% group_by(birthState = case_when(!birthState %in% state.abb ~ "Other", 
                                            TRUE ~ birthState)) %>% summarise(Players = n_distinct(playerID), 
                                                                              G = sum(G), AB = sum(AB),
                                                                              R = sum(R), H = sum(H), X2B = sum(X2B), X3B = sum(X3B),
                                                                              HR = sum(HR), RBI = sum(RBI), SB = sum(SB), CS = sum(CS),
                                                                              BB = sum(BB), SO = sum(SO), IBB = sum(IBB), HBP = sum(HBP),
                                                                              SH = sum(SH), SF = sum(SF), GIDP = sum(GIDP))
```

This gives me the data frame I want. Now my code for kmeans is:

```
subDat5 <- finalUpdate[, c(2:19)]
subDatSc5 <- scale(subDat5)
distDat5 <- dist(subDatSc5)
k2<-5
km3new<-kmeans(subDatSc5, k2, nstart = 40)
fitNew <-cmdscale(distDat5) # k is the number of dim to PLOT
plot(fitNew, xlab="Coordinate 1",ylab="Coordinate 2", pch=16, col=km3new$cluster)
birthState=as.character(finalUpdate[,1])
View(birthState)
text(fitNew+.1, labels = birthState, cex=.5)
```

Everything seems to work perfectly up until the last line, when I label all the points and it outputs a graph with each point being labeled 50 times.

Is there any fix to this?

dput(fitNew) =

```
structure(c(-1.65773726259238, -0.534080004429963, -1.25224081559503, 
-0.77600324658737, 13.7591986092784, -1.48285027332317, -1.0685046710528, 
-1.40697098882713, 4.45857203274176, 1.31053002832658, -1.35540549966184, 
-1.29910272287957, -1.68908570162927, 0.480144496416969, -0.592812161743823, 
-1.23667901504586, -0.844421560951474, -0.827147650450116, -1.22861495063773, 
-1.09472770146309, -1.68944621276222, -1.04378183282088, -1.34915033496973, 
-0.951660697104605, -0.45483103293441, -1.70655513856763, -0.0616193106609581, 
-1.48510165062592, -1.46251714293967, -1.66524625215651, -0.302561452071198, 
-1.56675666458699, -1.28344728331308, 0.864956587539308, 0.16173394975142, 
-0.850595975621662, -0.756783746315003, 24.7256817273653, -0.427398940139082, 
-1.39925870808987, -0.755785801532488, -1.51858748511865, -0.944152303255372, 
2.99465893267538, -1.67729960185572, -0.428860890332761, -1.66997803522651, 
-0.392867003697617, -1.30257694125332, -1.66036447381944, -1.6019072254532, 
-0.0137738939595427, -0.296070047308066, -0.00473553953140588, 
0.0641385777789144, 1.13842140049119, -0.0268651281540734, -0.128806499497676, 
-0.00491611456401126, 0.364126276181306, -0.143046769591177, 
-0.0283493696039194, -0.0485069239634975, -0.0287370449451863, 
0.095714493198601, -0.124528071666917, -0.0332600735692987, 0.0352695212129851, 
-0.119261467201306, -0.0381525968696119, 0.0551469698282207, 
-0.0115458694920637, -0.0250933419027217, 0.0406395856647227, 
0.12482265126378, -0.17954163594865, -0.0113245644618699, -0.0894498877336694, 
0.0305207676977073, 0.0323710265810206, -0.0491296972494748, 
-0.121635810491615, 0.0175346179372083, 0.0127983868546243, 0.21663582448027, 
0.0803333481747664, -0.0309611163272855, 0.0201356804088859, 
-0.696293053438086, 0.133550765173667, 0.108119095159391, -0.136003613852937, 
0.00557290379285935, 0.0602630898597761, -0.196004062948666, 
-0.0161895096280255, -0.178283625530885, -0.0170000868214074, 
0.107232630021258, 0.0375464632562086, -0.00276496483054615, 
0.0193363060673037), .Dim = c(51L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    NULL))
```

and dput(birthState) =

```
"c(\"AK\", \"AL\", \"AR\", \"AZ\", \"CA\", \"CO\", \"CT\", \"DE\", \"FL\", \"GA\", \"HI\", \"IA\", \"ID\", \"IL\", \"IN\", \"KS\", \"KY\", \"LA\", \"MA\", \"MD\", \"ME\", \"MI\", \"MN\", \"MO\", \"MS\", \"MT\", \"NC\", \"ND\", \"NE\", \"NH\", \"NJ\", \"NM\", \"NV\", \"NY\", \"OH\", \"OK\", \"OR\", \"Other\", \"PA\", \"RI\", \"SC\", \"SD\", \"TN\", \"TX\", \"UT\", \"VA\", \"VT\", \"WA\", \"WI\", \"WV\", \"WY\")"
```

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you provide some data. We can't guess what it looks like (specifically `fitNew` and `birthState`). You can use `dput(x)` or `dput(head(x))` to give us something to work with.

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `text(data+.1, ...)` to offset your labels. the function has a `pos` argument that you can use to place labels below (1), left (2), above (3) or right (4) of the specified coordinates.

Comment: @RomainB. Hi Romain. I did provide you with some data. I actually gave all the information my code has and said it was from the Lahman database, so there wasn't anything else I could give to you

Comment: @RomainB. However, since you asked for dput(fitNew) here it is anyways. It's now updated at the bottom of my post

Comment: Your problem is that `birthState`is not actually a character vector, but a string of the vector. I transformed `birthState` into its evaluated version and plotted the labels with no problem.

Comment: Also, the reason I asked for the data of your last 2 objects is that your problem is clearly due to them. Everything before that is not really relevant. I understand it can be a little difficult to scout where the pb originates from, but looking inside your variables takes you a long way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your problem is probably due to the fact that `birthState` is a string of an R character vector and not the actual vector.

The following code

```
birthState <- eval(parse(text = birthState))
plot(fitNew, xlab="Coordinate 1",ylab="Coordinate 2", pch=16)
text(fitNew, labels = birthState, cex=.5, pos = 4)
```

Yielded this for me

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that helped me with my error. I knew the error was coming from `birthState` but couldn't figure out why. Thanks!